# How to delete the row in array of arrays if all elements of the row are not values (NaN, null, undefined)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Tell me please how to delete the whole row in a 2D array if every element of this row is not a value (delete if NaN, delete if null, delete if undefined and so on...). If at least one element of the row is a number, a string, a boolean or any meaningful value then keep every element of this row on its place.

For example, in this array:

```js
var array = [];

array[0] = [];
array[1] = [];
array[2] = [];

array[0][1] = "title";
array[0][2] = NaN;
array[0][3] = 3;

array[1][0] = 0;
array[1][1] = undefined;
array[1][2] = null;
array[1][3] = 3;

array[2][0] = "title";
array[2][1] = 1;
array[2][2] = undefined;
array[2][3] = "url";

console.log(array);
```

delete array[0][2], array[1][2], array[2][2]. The expected result is:

> [ [ undefined, "title", 3 ], [ 0, undefined, 3 ], [ "title", 1, "url" ] ]

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Objective here is to help you with your code not to be a free code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl. You are right. I tried this array2 = array.map(subarray => subarray.filter(el => el != null)); But I don't know how to include Nan and undefined.

Comment: should undefined be included ?

Comment: You wrote in your question "...then keep every element of this row in its place...", but in your final output you are actually removing (and thus moving) elements. That is contradictory.

Comment: @trincot note that the input in your answer is not the same as the input in this code. You forgot the implicit `undefined` in [0][0], and the row that's being removed is [...][2] or `NaN, null, undefined`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, it is not my question?

Comment: Then why do you comment here?

Comment: Because your comment here is not true. There's no contradiction, just a misunderstanding that this is actually a column-major 2d array, not a row-major 2d array, and so every element of each row _is_ kept in its place unless the row is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the columns first and then splice the arrays.

```js
var array = [
        [, "title", NaN, 3],
        [0, undefined, null, 3],
        ["title", 1, undefined, "url"]
    ],
    indices = array
        .reduce((r, a) => {
            a.forEach((v, i) => r[i] = r[i] || !isNaN(v) && v !== null);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .reduceRight((r, v, i) => (v || r.push(i), r), []);

array.forEach(a => indices.forEach(i => a.splice(i, 1)));

console.log(indices);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Love it, especially this part `(r, v, i) => (v || r.push(i), r)`.

Comment: @Nina Scholz, could you explain a bit how this thing works?

Comment: which one? the `reduce`, `reduceRight` or `forEach`?

Comment: @Nina Scholz, I understand `reduce`, `reduceRight` and `forEach`. But I can't get the whole idea of `r[i] = r[i] || !isNaN(v) && v !== null); return r;`

Comment: as you see, it starts with an undefined item of `r[i]` and keeps gets either `false` for unwanted items or `true` for wanted items at the same indes, which is the column of the array. the result is an array for this given data of `[true, true, false, true]`, which represents which column should be kept.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(let y = 0; y < array[0].length; y++) {
    if(array.every(col => isNaN(col[y]) || col[y] == null)) {
      for(const col of array) col.splice(y, 1);
      y--;
    }
  }
```

Go over all columns, check if one is `NaN` or `null`, then filter the row.

Comment: thank you,but unfortunatelly it's not working https://playcode.io/156503?tabs=console&script.js&output

Comment: @jooms yup, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete rows in a column-major 2d array, it's easiest to pivot, [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and then pivot again. The filter is pretty straightforward:

```
row => !row.every(v => v == null || isNaN(v))))
```

But pivot is a little less intuitive:

```
var pivot = a => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(b => b[i]))
```

We assume that the 2d array is not jagged, so the length of `a[0]` should be the same as the length of the rest of the subarrays. We then map it and use the index parameter to map the outer array to the `i`th element of each inner array.

The full code is below:

```js
var array = [
  [undefined, 'title', NaN, 3],
  [0, undefined, null, 3],
  ['title', 1, undefined, 'url']
];

var pivot = a => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(b => b[i]))
var rotated = pivot(array)
var filtered = rotated.filter(row => !row.every(v => v == null || isNaN(v)))
var result = pivot(filtered)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: yep, I guess the poster confused "rows" and "columns" in their question. If yes, this is the right solution. `pivot` is usually called `zip` in JS circles...

Comment: @georg I've always thought of `zip` like [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I, like many others, might be too used to python, where it's `zip(many things)` and often (ab)used to transpose matrices. In the literal sense, zip is actually about exactly two things... so yes, you have a point.